# angularjs conditional http get request in view

Tags: angularjs, get

I have a url in my view that when clicked it downloads an excel file.
I want to add an angular-spinner to that dialog box so that the spinner is shown when the file is being downloaded.

I can start and stop the spinner in the controller but if i put the get request there, I don't get an excel file back.

Is it there any way to do this from the view? or any other option?

Thank you

PS:
The code below is the href link in the view 
I want to add the angular-spinner when the export button is clicked and the file is being downloaded and stop when its complete

```
<DIV>
      <a type="media_type" class="btn btn-primary"
                   href="/api/prj/report/job/{{jobId}}">Export</a>
            </div>
```

The html code for the spinner is as follow and I can use it but because my http get request is in the view, I want to know how I can know whether the file is being downloaded (so that i show the spinner) and stop it when its complete

```
<span us-spinner spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
```

Comment: please show your code... We can't help you with so few information

Comment: i added some extra information.

Comment: I read that I can't make an href request from the controller because of how angular works. is it there anyway to intercept the href call from the view to the server and act on the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with the following markup

```
  <span ng-if="serverIsProcessing" us-spinner spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
  <a type="media_type" class="btn btn-primary"
               ng-click="export({{jobId}})">Export</a>
```

Inside your controller, add the following function (don't forget to add a dependency to '$window' and '$resource') :

```
 $scope.serverIsProcessing = false;

 $scope.export = function(jobId){
      $scope.serverIsProcessing = true;
      $resource("/api/prj/report/job/" + jobId).get(function(id){
           $window.open("/api/downloadTempFile/" + jobId);
           $scope.serverIsProcessing = false;
      }, function(error){
           //Handle error if needed
      });
 };
```

On your controller you will need 2 actions :

- action to create the file and store it on a location for temporary files
- action to download the file previously created (and delete it after the file has been downloaded).

Comment: The export button is on a dialog box, the spinner is used to show the file is being downloaded, once the download is complete the spinner disappears. that's why I am trying to use the spinner so that the user knows that the server is still processing my request.

Comment: what do you mean by "still processing my request"?

Comment: when i click the export button, a request is made on the server, data relevant to that request is then gathered from the database and finally an excel file is created. when the request of data is big, it can some time take a few seconds before the server responds to my export action. I want o make sure that the hanging time in between me clicking the export button and the server responding, can be dealt with a spinner on the screen.